# JavaScript: Get parent element values on click event

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm completely new to JavaScript and struggling to get this working. I'm trying to display contact details in an alert box when a button is clicked.

The information is displayed in nested DIVs outlined below:

```
<div class="info-and-actions">
<div class="info">
  <div class="name-container">
    <h4 class="name"><a href="#" title="Name" class="name-link">Trader 1</a></h4>
  </div>
<div class="details-container">
  <p class="tele">###############</p>
  <p class="email">hello@url.com</p>
</div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="displayContactDetails">Display contact details</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="info-and-actions">
<div class="info">
  <div class="name-container">
    <h4 class="name"><a href="#" title="Name" class="name-link">Trader 2</a></h4>
  </div>
<div class="details-container">
  <p class="tele">###############</p>
  <p class="email">hello@url.com</p>
</div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="displayContactDetails">Display contact details</button>
  </div>
```

I am using this JavaScript with an event listener on the displayContactDetails button to display the contact details in the alert box.

```
function displayContactDetails() {
var contactName = document.querySelector("a.name-link.profile-link").textContent;
var contactTele = document.querySelector("p.tele").textContent;
alert("Contact " + contactName + " on " + contactTele);
}
```

This currently displays the first trader's contact details when any displayContactDetails button is clicked.

What I want to do is select the relevant contact information from the parent elements of the button (.name-container and .details-container) - so when the second button is clicked, Trader 2's details are displayed.

How do I traverse the DOM to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your event will have the necessary info to locate the corresponding telephone element.

```
function displayContactDetails(e) {
    var contactName = e. currentTarget  // this is the element that has the click listener
        .parentNode  // this would be .actions div
        .parentNode  // this would be .info div
        .querySelector('.name a')  // the link with the name
        .innerHTML; // the inner contents of the link, in this case the name

    // repeat but change querySelector to grab the telephone

    alert("Contact " + contactName + " on " + contactTele);
}
```

or easier with jquery

```
$('.displayContactDetails').on('click', function(e){
    var name = $(this)
              .closest('.info') // goes up in the tree until .info
              .find('.name').html(); // then back to .name and get content

    alert(name);
});
```

With jquery it is not only easier, but it is also more resilient to changes in the html structure. Jquery will go up the DOM tree until it finds the `.info` div. With plain js you have to hardcode the number of times to jump to the parent element, or make a loop for it.

You can also try the other answers suggested but you also have to maintain the additional id's and markup required for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

i hope passing a unique info on the function call

```js
          function displayContactDetails(id){
            var contactName = document.getElementById("name-link-"+id).textContent;
        
            alert("Contact " + contactName );
          }
```

```html
    <div class="info-and-actions">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="name-container">
        <h4 class="name"><a href="#" title="Name" id="name-link-one">Trader 1</a></h4>
      </div>
    <div class="details-container">
      <p class="tele">###############</p>
      <p class="email">hello@url.com</p>
    </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <button class="displayContactDetails" onclick="displayContactDetails('one')">Display contact details</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="info-and-actions">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="name-container">
        <h4 class="name"><a href="#" title="Name" id="name-link-two">Trader 2</a></h4>
      </div>
    <div class="details-container">
      <p class="tele">###############</p>
      <p class="email">hello@url.com</p>
    </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <button class="displayContactDetails" onclick="displayContactDetails('two')">Display contact details</button>
      </div>
```